# In Css, how can I select an elements children together?

Tags: css, css-selectors, stylish

Hey guys I'm trying to put a border around a few elements on this page using Stylish (Chrome Extension). Here is the structure of how the page is, the letters representing a different class..

```
A
  B
  B
  C
  C
```

I want to put the border around the "C"s, if I do it just by calling the C class, I would end up with border's between the two C classes. So is there a way I can select both the C's together as one element.

With Stylish you cannot change the HTML of a page, just css, I know I could just nest it in HTML, but that's not an option.

Edit: C also appears in other area's of the page.

Comment: If there is no gap between the C's, you could put a border on the top, left, and right of the first. And then a border on the bottom, left, and right of the second.

Comment: Just that structure ? something like this : `.c {border:thin solid red} .c+.c {border-top:none} ` but if the structure is more complex for example more elements on C or more elements after C will be more tricky

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/j6zm908c/1/) could work. Though as @DaniP points out, once you get any more complicated than your exact example, things get hazy.

Comment: No, sorry, didn't mention C also shows up other places in the page. Here's how that shows up on the page http://prntscr.com/el97lh

Comment: @Dexus is that my solution or DaniP's? Not to single it out but I don't think DaniP's solution quite works for your example, either: https://jsfiddle.net/j6zm908c/2/ - Though my implementation might be different than what he/she had in mind.

Comment: Really didn't get the problem with that tiny screenshot

Comment: @Santi Yours works! I was directing that last one to Dani. Thank you! Sorry, I'm not to keen on web design.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```css
.a>.c {
  border: solid red;
  border-width: 0 1px;
}
.a>*:not(.c) + .c,
.a>.c:first-child {
  border-top-width: 1px;
}
.a>.c + *:not(.c) {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
.a>.c:last-child {
  border-bottom-width: 1px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="a">
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="a">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="a">
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="a">
  <div class="c">C</div>
</div>
```

The only *"trick"* is that I have to use the top border of an immediately following element after a `.c` in order to place the *"bottom"* border of the last `.c` in a group of `.c`s. Currently there's no way to select a group of immediate siblings with a certain class. The point in evaluation when you know the last element with `.c` in a group is the last is when you evaluate the next item and see it doesn't have `.c`. But at that point, you can't style the element before, because `CSS` only parses forward, never backwards.

In short, if you have a margin between elements, there is no way to do only with `CSS` (******* see note). It would be trivial with `javascript` (I can provide it, if of any help).

---

******* Actually, you could make this work even if with margins between elements, by `null`-ing the margins between `.c` and any `:not(.c)` and applying the difference to the first child of the `:not(.c)` instead. It's cumbersome to find a magical solution that would work in any case. Most times, these things are coded looking at the existing elements and finding tricks to make it *"look like"* it works.
That's all we have right now. :)

Comment: _Currently there's no way to select a group of immediate siblings with a certain class._ Indeed. It's a real pain that we do not have `:nth-of-class` to complement `:nth-of-type`.

Comment: @Rounin neither of those would really help here, `:nth-of-whatever` would make a distinct collection of all `whatever`s in the parent. But we want to select distinct groups of `whatever` that are glued together separately. `CSS` is not ready for it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is no space between and of your `<div>`

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  min-height: 50px;
}
.c{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.c + .c{
  border-top-color: white;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

You will need to set the `border-top-color` to that of the background of `.c` - if you have margins at the bottom of `.c`, you will need to add that margin to the border width and apply the negative margin at the top.

Comment: This fails if `C` also appears alone or in a group of more than two.

Comment: @Quentin the OP stated that they want a border around `.c`, but no border between two or more adjacent `.c` - there is no mention of only applying the border when there are two or more and/or if it is a descendant of `.a`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution which will account for any number of `.c` elements, you need to apply:

- a border-left and a border-right to all `.c` elements
- a border-top to the first `.c` element
- a border-bottom to the last `.c` element

But. There is no `:nth-of-class` pseudo-selector.

So:

- the first `.c` element can be selected (instead) with `.b + .c`.
- the last `.c` element can be selected (instead) with `:last-of-type`

**Working Example:**

```css
section {
width: 120px;
text-align: center;
background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}

div {
padding: 3px;
}

.c {
border-right: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
border-left: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 0); 
}

.b + .c {
border-top: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

div:last-of-type.c {
border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<section>
<div class="a">a</div>
<div class="b">b</div>
<div class="b">b</div>
<div class="c">c</div>
<div class="c">c</div>
</section>
```